# If a continuous $f$ is analytic on the unit disk without a slice, then $f$ is analytic on the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

**Exercise** If $f$ is continuous on the unit disk $|z| <1$ and analytic on $\{z=a+bi \in \mathbb{C}: |z| <1, b \neq 0\}$, then $f$ is analytic on the unit disk.

Alternatively, we mean that $f$ is continuous on $|z| < 1$ and analytic on $|z| < 1$ without the real axis. Then we must show that $f$ is in fact analytic on all of $|z| < 1$.

What are we to do to prove this? Is there a fundamental lemma/corollary/theorem that would elucidate this point?

Comment: Morera theorem works - this problem has been asked quite a few times before so if do a search you will find more details

Comment: @Conrad I see, thanks. What key words would be beneficial to search? It's hard to word a problem like this

Comment: You can use morera theorem by asserting the contour integral of around a triangle is zero which can be done by a limiting argument by continuity. You can find this theorem in Rudin's textbook(REAL and COMPLEX ANALYSIS theorem 10.17)